# In AngularJs When i call function not able to get $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scope

In angularjs when i click on button,then it will call function of Controller but in that function i am not able to get $scope or $rootScope.

Here is link :
https://plnkr.co/edit/rFDGLPMdvW4BeTBdu5s8?p=preview

when you click on Go To Store.. store page will open.. and click on Add to Cart.. then $scope function will call..but not getting $scope in that function`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You have a top-level controller called 'MainController'. The Store.html view uses this controller, but the AddToCart function is located in the StoreController. You need to add the Store controller to the store view (top line of store.html):

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController">
```

[Updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/aWElJkC8nUSEgsz4ZhTH?p=preview)

Comment: I have logged $scope in the AddToCart function (see plunkr) and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your app is working fine and if you open Developer tools you will see that the `debugger` breakpoint is being hit. The issue that I found is that you don't have the route defined for Cart. Also the `$scope.cartItemCount` won't be auto-updated